# Is there a function that will return the current frame of an animation?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to freeze my animation at a particular frame if the player is shooting rapidly. Something like this:

```
if (timeBetweenShots < 0.3f && timeBetweenShots > 0.0f && animator.GetCurrentFrame() == 20) 
{
        animator.enabled = false;
}
```

I see there is a animator.GetCurrentAnimationClipState() but that doesn't look like what I need, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: maybe this http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationState-clip.html

Comment: I dont think this is how Animator works. Consider creating an animation state "freeze" (with only 1 frame if you want) then trigger it when you need.